# Override an interface method but using argument of a derived class

Tags: c#

I want to create a structure of Services all of them derived from the interface `IService` which has an only method `Perform`

In order to allow the derived classes to define the kind of arguments the specific Perform implementations need I encapsulate such arguments in an interface called `IConfig`

The problem is that I can not access to the derived class properties in my custom Perform implementations because I am forced to *type* the argument as `IConfig`

Is there any way I can override an interface/abstract class method with arguments of derived class of the interface's method's argument's class?

Example:

```
interface IConfig {}

class Config : IConfig
{
    public int Property;
}

interface IService
{
    void Perform(IConfig config);
}

class Service : IService
{
    void IService.Perform(IConfig config)
    {
        config.Property;
    }
}
```

With the above `Service` implementation I get the error:

> 'IConfig' does not contain a definition for 'Property'

If I change it to this:

```
class Service : IService
{
    void IService.Perform(Config config)
    {
        config.Property;
    }
}
```

I get the errors:

> 'Service' does not implement interface member 'IService.Perform(IConfig)'

and

> 'Service.Perform(Config)' in explicit interface declaration is not found among members of the interface that can be implemented

I am wondering if there is something like:

```
void IService.Perform((IConfig)Config config)
```

or

```
void IService.Perform(Config config as IConfig)
```

or

```
(Config)config.Property
```

Comment: Why isn't the property part of the interface then?

Comment: @asaf92 different implementations of `IConfig` have different _Properties_

Comment: So why are you looping over `IConfig` and not over `Config` references? The whole point of holding references to an interface is that your code doesn't need to know the implementation details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Using generics

This is the perfect case for using generics.

```
interface IConfig { }

class Config : IConfig
{
    public int Property;
}

interface IService<T> where T : IConfig
{
    void Perform(T config);
}

class Service : IService<Config>
{
    public void Perform(Config config)
    {
        config.Property;
    }
}
```

Generics reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

`where` reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint

---

Be aware by making a class or interface generic you cannot reduce it to a non-generic form like `IService` without changing it so that the generic form extends from a non-generic base like so:

```
interface IService
{

}

interface IService<T> : IService where T : IConfig
{
    void Perform(T config);
}
```

This removes the access to the properties of the generic form when cast to `IService` (which is obvious when you think about it). You'll have to cast it back to its correct generic type (`IService<Config>`) to access those properties which might cause a headache when dealing with collections (`List<IService>` for example) of multiple generic types.

To avoid this you can settle for using simple casting.

## Using casting

If you don't care about compile-time restrictions on the type of the config and you DO care about the `List<IService>` problem above, you can go for a run-time alternative like so:

```
interface IConfig { }

class Config : IConfig
{
    public int Property;
}

interface IService
{
    void Perform(IConfig config);
}

class Service : IService
{
    void IService.Perform(IConfig config)
    {
        if (!(config is Config)) throw new ArgumentException("Expected config to be of type Config");

        Config castedConfig = (Config)config;
        castedConfig.Property;
    }
}
```

This will ***NOT*** prevent you from calling `Perform` with a config of the incorrect type through compile-time restrictions but it WILL throw an `ArgumentException` on run-time if you do call it with a config of the incorrect type.